# How to make procedure to get data from different table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating an stored procedure in SQL to get the data like:

```
  {
            "UserID": 1,
            "UserName": "Ravi",
            "Password": "2222",
            "Email_ID": "a@gmail.com",
            "UserProfileImageURL": "https://",
            "Skills": {
                        "SkillDesc": "iOS",
                        "SkillDesc": "Android",
             }
 }
```

----------- my Stored procedure is like---------

```
SELECT users.*,  
       profiles.Details,
       profiles.Experiance,
       profiles.HoursCompleated,
       profiles.RatePerHour,
       profiles.SubTitle,
       profiles.TotalEarning     
FROM      Users users
LEFT JOIN profile profiles
ON     users.UserID = profiles.UserID
WHERE  users.UserType = 'Coach' 
AND    users.UserID = 1
```

How to get data from Skills table and add inside the my stored procedure?

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Comment: Can you show us your tables structure and relationship mapping details?

Comment: Kindly share schema and some sample data with desired output

Comment: @Alex It is SQL Database and in which as per one user there will be multiple skills.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh I mean which DBMS you use for example Mysql, SQL-Server, Oracle etc. .

Comment: @Alex SQL Server

Comment: @AmandeepSingh you have to provide us the structure of all the tables you use in your example (profile, Users, skill). We cant help you if we do not now the table structure! Please take a look at this info page: [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info), to learn how to write good sql questions.

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is right, your skills table will have a user id column OR your profile column will have a skills id column.

Either way left join your skills table in to your query as below and then present your skills columns in the select list.

Also usually an alias after a table name is used to shorten the reference you need to type in to the query such as "Profile p". Just makes it a little easier on yourself rather than using an alias that is longer like "profiles" for the "Profile" table.

```
SELECT users.*, profiles.Details, profiles.Experiance, 
profiles.HoursCompleated, profiles.RatePerHour, 
profiles.SubTitle, profiles.TotalEarning FROM Users users 
LEFT JOIN profile profiles ON users.UserID = 
profiles.UserID
LEFT JOIN Skills ON users.UserID=Skills.UsersID WHERE 
users.UserType = 'Coach' AND users.UserID = 1
```

Comment: In the skills table one user may have multiple skills records then how to handle multiple skills records as per one user?

Comment: A left join works by showing every matching case in the right table (here the skills table) with all cases in the left table (here the users table). So you will see a row per user per skill. So if "Hank" has 2 skills. You will see 2 rows for him. If he has 0 skills you will see 1 row for him with a null for the skills column (you can you coaleasce(skill, '') to handle the null).